# Why is KiCad repeatedly re-assigning the Ground Pin of a row of resistors to some random pad?

Tags: resistors, pcb-design, kicad, pins, pad

I have run into an odd problem with KiCad, whereby a row of resistors has its ground pads re-assigned to some random pad. This happened with the central row of resistors first of all, which were showing a connection label on each ground pad to some pad instead of GND, and after I reworked the schematic so that each row of resistors had its own GND connection (see the schematic diagram below) the middle row or resistors went back to normal, i.e. showing they needed to be connected to GND, which I duly did.

Now when I look at the row of resistors on the right, I see they all are expected to be connected to Net - (R17 Pad 1), which is a single resistor elsewhere in the circuit. Is KiCad trying to push me in the direction of some shortcut or optimization I don't know about?

[image: schematic]

[image: row of reassigned-pin resistors]

[image: weird pad assignment example]

Comment: One reason it may happen is when a trace already exists between two different nets it the layout (because the layout was made before changing schematics), forcing them to be the same net. Try deleting all traces in the PCB (of course, don't click save) to see if it's the case.

Comment: Doing it now, thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

OK I'm optimistic that someone will post a better answer, but since the following procedure worked, and I'm not sure why, this might be a starting point for other people facing the same problem. Thanks @比尔盖子 for the heads up in the comment above.

I went back to KiCad and simply joined up all eight resistor 'GND' pins since they and the net pin they were indicating they should be linked to were all in a straight line and a single straight trace across all the pins did what KiCad was asking.

I then got an error reporting an anomaly between the Schematic and the PCB Layout. When I went back and modified the schematic again, separating the isolated 'target' component's GND pin from the other 8 resistors so that there were two separate nets in the schematic (you can see the original design in the first image above) and updated the PCB Layout, the pins magically returned to their correct state, all labelled with GND as intended. Voila!

I'm assuming some sort of weird internal thing in KiCad was happening. But I am a beginner, and that's just a guess. So quite possibly this problem was actually a feature, rather than a bug.

Oh and here's the finished board after that headache:

[image: poor man's debugger for a 65C02]